# Using a while loop to indefinitely reassign a variable, until that variable no longer belongs to a list?

Tags: python-3.x, random, while-loop

The purpose of this program is to deal out one 5-card hand from a standard 52-card deck.

I'm new to Python. Eventually I'd like to write a 5-card draw poker program, but first would like to know how to deal out 5 random non-repeating cards. The cards get dealt out and printed back to the user fine, but it is sometimes dealing duplicates. ie, the hand I'm dealt is Ah 2d 8h Ah Jc. Can't have two ace of hearts.

I'm trying to use a while True: construction to ensure that the same card isn't dealt twice. I studied C for awhile before Python and am confused here in syntax/construction. A do-while loop would seem to be handy, where it indefinitely reassigns the card to a random int as long as that card hasn't been drawn yet.

The code is also super long and I've just shown the process for assigning the first few cards. Using 52 if statements seems to a problem, but first I'd like to see if it can run with this construction, just fixing the while loop.

```
import random


# track a list of cards used
dealt_cards = ["Joker", "Joker2"]

for n in range (5):
    # generate a random int between 1 and 52 representing card
    card = random.randint(1,52)

    #check to see if this card has already been dealt,  
    #and if so, re-deal
    while True:
        if card in dealt_cards:
            card = random.randint(1,52)
        else:
            break


    #assign each random int generation to a specific card in the 
    deck,
    #and add the new card to dealt_cards

    #spades
    if card == 1:
        card = str(card)
        card = 'As'
        dealt_cards.append(card)
    if card == 2:
        card = str(card)
        card = '2s'
        dealt_cards.append(card)
    if card == 3:
        card = str(card)
        card = '3s'
        dealt_cards.append(card)
    if card == 4:
        card = str(card)
        card = '4s'
        dealt_cards.append(card)
    if card == 5:
        card = str(card)
        card = '5s'
        dealt_cards.append(card)
    if card == 6:
        card = str(card)
        card = '6s'
        dealt_cards.append(card)
```

I expect the program to return 5 unique non - repeating playing cards to the user, but it sometimes returns (deals) the same card twice in the same hand.

Comment: You seriously need to take a look at [random.sample()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can create all cards from 2 lists (suits, faces).

You can either make a shuffled copy of the deck or draw 5 random cards without replacement (random.sample):

```
import itertools
import random

suits = ['heart', 'tiles', 'clubs', 'pikes']
faces = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'T', 'J', 'Q', 'K']

deck = set(itertools.product(faces, suits))

# get a mixed sample of all cards, use get first 5 cards
mixed = random.sample(deck, len(deck)) # get sample of all cards from deck (==shuffled copy) 
five = mixed[:5]
print(five) 

# to remove the just drawn cards from availables:
mixed = mixed[5:] # to remove the drawn cards for your mixed copy

# draw 7 non-repeated cards from deck
seven = random.sample(deck, 7)  # get 7 unique cards directly from deck
print(seven)
```

Output:

```
# five
[('6', 'pikes'), ('T', 'heart'), ('Q', 'pikes'), ('3', 'tiles'), ('J', 'clubs')]

# seven
[('A', 'tiles'), ('7', 'tiles'), ('8', 'tiles'), ('3', 'heart'), ('9', 'pikes'),
 ('6', 'heart'), ('T', 'clubs')]
```

Deckbuilding inspired by: [codereview texas-holdem-poker-game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/144935/texas-holdem-poker-game)

Takeing from a copy of `deck` that is preshuffled makes it easy to deal cards. Simply take from the front to "deal" and list.pop(0) this element.

Doku:

- [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to create the deck from 2 lists
- [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)
- [random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) for a inplace-shuffling of a list

---

Itertools product is a fance multiple for loop:

```
d = []
for s in suits:
    for f in faces:
        d.append((s,f))

print(d)

[('heart', 'A'), ('heart', '2'), ('heart', '3'), ('heart', '4'), ('heart', '5'), 
 ('heart', '6'), ('heart', '7'), ('heart', '8'), ('heart', '9'), ('heart', 'T'), 
 ('heart', 'J'), ('heart', 'Q'), ('heart', 'K'), ('tiles', 'A'), ('tiles', '2'), 
 ('tiles', '3'), ('tiles', '4'), ('tiles', '5'), ('tiles', '6'), ('tiles', '7'), 
 ('tiles', '8'), ('tiles', '9'), ('tiles', 'T'), ('tiles', 'J'), ('tiles', 'Q'),
 ('tiles', 'K'), ('clubs', 'A'), ('clubs', '2'), ('clubs', '3'), ('clubs', '4'), 
 ('clubs', '5'), ('clubs', '6'), ('clubs', '7'), ('clubs', '8'), ('clubs', '9'), 
 ('clubs', 'T'), ('clubs', 'J'), ('clubs', 'Q'), ('clubs', 'K'), ('pikes', 'A'), 
 ('pikes', '2'), ('pikes', '3'), ('pikes', '4'), ('pikes', '5'), ('pikes', '6'), 
 ('pikes', '7'), ('pikes', '8'), ('pikes', '9'), ('pikes', 'T'), ('pikes', 'J'), 
 ('pikes', 'Q'), ('pikes', 'K')]
```